# Summing up Rows based on similar column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

Here is an example data frame

```
ID    Var1    Var2    Var3 ....... Var85
A      3       2        1            3
B      1       3        1            2
A      2       1        1            1
A      1       2        2            1
C      3       1        3            2
C      2       1        2            1
B      1       3        3            1
```

I want to create the following, basically summing up rows based on ID

```
ID    Var1    Var2    Var3 ....... Var85
A      6       5        4            5
B      2       2        4            3
C      5       6        5            3
```

I found a solution for only a single variable using the dplyr, but I know how to implement that with multiple columns

> df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Var1 = sum(Var2)) %>% as.data.frame()

I thought of implementing the following via a loop, but I am hoping for a much simpler solution.

Comment: Use `across` inside `summarise`: `df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(Var1:Var85, ~ sum(.x)))`

Comment: This was a example dataframe, My actual dataframe doesn't have the colnames in such a good representation

Comment: I can use your solution, by doing the following, export the colnames out in a vector, then rename the colnames as above, then apply the solution and then import back the colnames.

Comment: Well, without seeing a piece of your dataset, it is hard to offer a better solution.

Comment: The dataset is not much different, instead of the column names as c(Var1:Var85), they look like c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, .........., omega )

Comment: If these columns of yours are sequential, then use: `df %>%    group_by(ID) %>%    summarise(across(alpha:omega, ~ sum(.x)))`.

Comment: this isn't working, the error

Comment: Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything() ~ sum(.x))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 0: character(0).
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Must supply a column selection.
ℹ You most likely meant: `across(everything(), everything() ~ sum(.x))`.
ℹ The first argument `.cols` selects a set of columns.
ℹ The second argument `.fns` operates on each selected columns.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Post the `colnames` of your dataframe.

Comment: "ID", "X1.16" ,"X1.16.1","X1.16.2","X1.17"   "X1.17.1" "X1.17.2" "X1.17.3" , "X1.18"........ and so on

Comment: This works: `df <- data.frame(
                ID = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B"),
                X1.16 = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L),
                X1.16.1 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L),
                X1.16.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L),
                X1.17 = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)
      )

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(X1.16:X1.17, ~ sum(.x)))`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `across(2:5` instead of `across(X1.16:X1.17`.

Comment: I see that the class of the columns of my data are factors, is it the reason it is problemetic, and your dataset is numeric

Comment: So, do this: `df %>%    group_by(ID) %>%    summarise(across(X1.16:X1.17, ~ sum(.x %>% as.numeric)))`. `as.numeric` will convert your factors to numbers before summing.

Comment: you meant only   df %>%    group_by(ID) %>%    summarise(across(X1.16:X1.17, ~ sum(.x %>% as.numeric))),......which works perfectly

Comment: thanks a lot for helping out, should have cross-checked my classes in the dataframe @PaulS

Comment: Excellent, Maharnab Naha!